# Set image control image dynamically from server side asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, datalist, databound, asp.net-controls, datalistitem

I have a webforms site where users upload files, the file name etc is saved to DB. These files are then displayed in a datalist. I'm trying to get this datalist to show different images (icons) to represent the file types.

This is my code behind. *fm.getIcon* is a custom function that returns the full file path on the server to the approppriate image which represents the file type.

When i debug the code i can verify that the image does exist at the *imgFile* path

```
Private Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemDataBound

        Dim docName As Label = e.Item.FindControl("fileNameLabel")
        Dim docImage As Image = e.Item.FindControl("image1")
        Dim imgFile As String = fm.getIcon(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(docName.Text).Extension)
        docImage.ImageUrl = imgFile

End Sub
```

My problem is that the image is not loading. If i replace imgFile with a hardcoded path to an image it works fine.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

**// 1st Method**

```
string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Images/MyFile.jpg");

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileLocation);

string fileExtension = fileInfo.Extension;
```

**// 2nd Method**

```
System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Server.MapPath("~/Images/MyFile.jpg")); // Result: .jpg
```

**// Your get icon method**

```
docImage.ImageUrl = "~/Icons/" + 
fm.getIcon(Path.GetExtension(Server.MapPath("~/Images/MyFile.jpg")));

public string getIcon(string extension)
{
  switch (extension.ToLower())
  {
    case ".asa":
      return "asa.png";
    case ".asax":
      return "asax.png";
    case ".ascx":
      return "ascx.png";                
    default:
      return "unknown.png";
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm using server.mappath in the getIcon function to return the correct URL.

Comment: You do not need Server.MapPath in getIcon method. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should confirm that `fm.getIcon` is actually returning a valid URL for the icon image, not a machine-level file path.  You should be able to take the output of `fm.getIcon` and paste it into a browser and see the image.  File permissions could be a issue, the IIS process serving the website needs to be able read the icon image files.

Comment: I can confirm that the path is correct and file does exist with correct permissions

Comment: In fact on the final rendered page, when i "View source" the paths are also correct